# How can I use Class or Id in Html helper in MVC 5, I've tried this but it didn't work for me

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using Html Helper with class but it didn't work for my code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <p class="form-title">YOUR NAME <span>(required)</span></p>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "normal-box"})
                <p class="form-title">YOUR EMAIL <span>(required)</span></p>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "normal-box" })
                <p class="form-title">SUBJECT</p>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subject, new { @class = "normal-box" })
                <p class="form-title">YOUR MESSEGE</p>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Messege, new { @class = "messege-box" })

                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
            }
```

Comment: _but it didn't work_? **What didn't work**? (the code you have shown does generate `<input ... class="normal-box" />`)

Comment: yes I've tried and used CSS in external file but still it didn't work.

Comment: Open chrome dev tools and see if you have any `404` errors for a `css` file in the `Console`

Comment: I've recreated Model class and form. Now problem solved. Thanks